# c++ and ublas: creating an array of c_vectors with different sizes

Tags: c++, arrays, ublas

Is there a way to create an array of ublas c_vectors with different sizes?

For example

`array[0]` would return an `ublas::c_vector< double, 3 >` (size=3) and `array[0](0)` would access its first element

`array[1]` would return an `ublas::c_vector< double, 7 >` (size=7) and `array[1](0)` would access its first element

etc

Comment: [If you want it to be a possessive...](http://www.homestarrunner.com/sbemail89.html)

Comment: Kerrek SB, thanks for the editing, its my first question

Comment: No problem. Using the backticks for code is especially important if you have those angled brackets, which would otherwise just disappear.

Comment: Functions `return` things. Nothing else `return`s anything.

Comment: @niels: Reading the instructions is especially important when it's your first time! Never understood how "it's my first question" was ever an excuse :/

Comment: @niels: Pretty much always, yes! I make use of FAQs and preview panes, because I am aware that they are presented for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `std::vector<boost::any>`, and then push `ublas::c_vector` of different sizes into it.

```
std::vector<boost::any> v;
v.push_back(ublas::c_vector<double,3>());
v.push_back(ublas::c_vector<double,7>());
v.push_back(ublas::c_vector<double,9>());
//etc
```

Elements should be cast back to the appropriate types, using [`boost::any_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/any_cast.html) which  is custom keyword cast for extracting a value of a given type from [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/any.html).

You could try `boost::variant` as well. Choose whatever suits your need better. Read this before making a decision:

- [Boost.Variant vs. Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant/misc.html#variant.versus-any)

Comment: That seems to be the only solution, given that vectors of different sizes don't share any common base class.

Comment: I tried this but a get a "call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function"

Also tried this 'boost::array<boost::any, 2> v = {ublas::c_vector<double,3>(), ublas::c_vector<double,7>()};' and got the same error

Comment: @KerrekSB: One could use `Variant` as well. But I don't know the exact  requirement.

Comment: @niels: With boost.any, you have to cast the elements back to the required type. I think it's `any_cast` or something like that, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Kerrek : It is `any_cast`. :-)